# SonarQube analysis

Tags: sonarqube-scan

In sonar qube analysis I have projects of different versions on which independent development is done.
But if I analyze these projects each analysis is shown in the same project in sonar.
I want to differentiate each version,
Is there a provision for such requirement.

Comment: Possibly a duplicate of [SonarQube - analyzing branches of the same project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24786176/sonarqube-analyzing-branches-of-the-same-project)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried the -Dsonar.projectkey in the maven argument to analyze sonar but it does not work, at least on versions of sonar above 5.6.6 Lts since I tried this on 5.6.6 and 6.3,
An alternative though which I found was -Dsonar.branch.
The argument would look like -Dsonar.branch=.
This works fine.